# Ensuring table is empty before data migration in order to not add duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, migration

When performing a data migration in tsql, how do we make sure the table is empty before we bring over the data in order to not add duplicates.

For example to see if a table exists we use:

```
if exists(select * from sys.objects where name='table name') drop table table name
go
```

What do we use to see if a table is populated or empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out row count with `select count(*)`, and then do a test on the return value.

```
if (select count(*) from dbo.YourTableName) > 0
begin
    -- handle condition where there are rows
end
else
begin
    -- handle condition where there are no rows of data
end;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to KNOW the table was populated?

You could do a

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
```

as a matter of course

To delete ONLY if the table is not empty, try

```
declare @tablecount int;
select @tablecount = count(*) from yourtable
if @tablecount > 0
begin
delete from yourtable
end
```